# How to delete a row, where one of my string is inside another string

Tags: sql-server

I have this problem, I'm building up a chain of nodes in sql servor but some of my chain are already contained in other chains:

```
ChainsOfNodes
1-2363
1-2363-4665
1-2363-4665-2359
```

For example the chain `1-2363` is contained in the chain `1-2363-4665`.
I want to delete that row because it's already contained into another chain.

Is there a easy way to delete these rows with a delete statment ?

I was using a cursor but the performance were really poor.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are there any other fields on this table? Also, will there be other chains of nodes with different formats?

Comment: It seems like you want to delete them all, cause 1 row contained in the second row and the seconde in the 3rd, and also the 1st one is contained in both rows (2 and 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([ChainsOfNodes] varchar(16));

INSERT INTO T
    ([ChainsOfNodes])
VALUES
    ('1-2363'),
    ('1-2363-4665'),
    ('1-2363-4665-2359');

DELETE T1
FROM  T T1 JOIN T T2 ON T2.ChainsOfNodes LIKE '%'+T1.ChainsOfNodes+'%'
WHERE T1.ChainsOfNodes <> T2.ChainsOfNodes;

SELECT *
FROM T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------------+
|  ChainsOfNodes   |
+------------------+
| 1-2363-4665-2359 |
+------------------+
```

Here is a **[Demo](https://rextester.com/VXAGQ98706)** where you can test.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete all records which are including '1-2363', you can use the below query.

```
--Run the below query and check the records first.
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ChainsOfNodes like '1-2363%'

--If above query return necessary records, you can run the below query to delete them
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ChainsOfNodes like '1-2363%'
```

--If you need to keep the last record, then you can use below query.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ChainsOfNodes in  ('1-2363' , '1-2363-4665')
```

Comment: But that would also delete the last entry of each chain, which doesn't seem to be the desired result. Also it's not very dynamic.

Comment: That is just a sample data, I don't think the OP want to do just for `1-2363`. So mybe there is `1-3535` and `1-3535-1414` in this case your code won't help.

Comment: Yeah, it was a sample data, with each iterations there will be addtionnal chains